# GPUImageMovieWriter - crashing with "Cannot call method when status is 2"

Tags: ios, avassetwriter, gpuimage

Trying to get started with the really great GPUImage framework so graciously shared by Brad Larson, but having an issue.

When running the SimpleVideoFileFilter sample it always crashes at completion with the following error:

[AVAssetWriterInput markAsFinished] Cannot call method when status is 2

Anyone know how to correct this?

Also do not see the video when run in simulator, does it not work for simulator?

Running iOS 6.1 and Xcode 4.6

Thanks!

I am noticing that finishRecordingWithCompletionHandler is being called twice, it crashes on second call

Comment: Is this with the latest code from the repository? This was a problem a few months ago, but it should have been fixed then.

Comment: Yes, this is from latest on github.

Comment: I noticed that finishRecordingWithCompletionHandler is called twice, so i put in a check if (isRecording == no) return; but not sure if this is correct fix

Comment: OK, that sounds like a bug. Create an issue for it on the GitHub project page (if one doesn't already exist among the 200+ open issues) and I or someone else might be able to fix it.