# AVAssetWriter startWriting Cannot call method when status is 3

Tags: ios, video-processing, gpuimage

I am working with Video filtering.I used GPUImage from 
[BradLarson](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). It perfect work on Images, but now I am trying to filter video file from Library it give me error `[AVAssetWriter startWriting] Cannot call method when status is 3`.
I used IOS7

heare is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    videoEditingPlayView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,108,200,200)];

    [self.view addSubview:videoEditingPlayView];
}

-(IBAction)btnEffectsClick:(id)sender{
     NSURL *videoURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.strVideoURl];
    if (movieFile != nil) {
        videoFilter = nil;
       movieFile = nil;
     }
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:videoURl];
movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
videoFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)videoFilter setBrightness:0.0];
[movieFile addTarget:videoFilter];
videoEditingPlayView.hidden = NO;

GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)videoEditingPlayView;
[videoFilter addTarget:filterView];

NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480, 360)];
[videoFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

// movieWriter.
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];
[filterView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio];
filterView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(filterView.transform, 3.14159/2);


double delayToStartRecording = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayToStartRecording * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(startTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"Start recording");
    [movieWriter startRecording];

    **[movieFile startProcessing];** ***if I remove this line then it is working but not dispying video on videoEditingPlayView***


    double delayInSeconds = 30.0;
    dispatch_time_t stopTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(stopTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
        [movieWriter finishRecording];

        [videoFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];

        movieWriter = nil;
        NSLog(@"Movie completed");
    });
});
}
```

in coding if I remove this line

**`[movieFile startProcessing]`;**

then app run smoothly, but not displaying video. if I put `[movieFile startProcessing]` then it crash and give me a error.

I tried this one but can't solved crash.

[GPUImage terminates due to [AVAssetWriter startWriting] Cannot call method when status is 3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327955/gpuimage-terminates-due-to-avassetwriter-startwriting-cannot-call-method-when)

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1228

[Blends with GPUImageView are not giving expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369684/blends-with-gpuimageview-are-not-giving-expected-result)

[GPUImageMovieWriter - crashing with "Cannot call method when status is 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075172/gpuimagemoviewriter-crashing-with-cannot-call-method-when-status-is-2?rq=1)

And also other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check your destination file is exist.

If exist, remove the exist file.